# Pausing an Application in Android

Tags: android, onpause

I am having a buttong in my Android App and I want that pressing that button should stop the application at the same point. While clicking again on the same button should resume the App.

How to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to pause your application? What are you trying to do?

Comment: what exactly you app is doing that it should be paused. give more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question. You should never pause and resume your app manually, that's for the system to do for you.

Comment: Ii think I got the answer. thanx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What does your application do? In any case, you will have to store and re-create your application state. You can store it in a file, SharedPreferences or an SQLite database.